# Checking user input to make sure each int is a number in Java

Tags: java

I am writing a program that will ask the user to enter in 10 numbers separated by spaces and then displays the distinct numbers. My problem is coming in if a user enters in anything other than a number the program crashes. I am trying to use a has next checker but I am not sure how to get it to check all 10 numbers before sending them to my array. Here is my code any advice would be appreciated.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;


public class DistinctNumbers 
{
    static double input;
    static int number;

   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
      char cont='N';

       do{
           menue();

           menueCatch();

           cont=contOption();


         }while(cont=='Y');
   }

    private static void menue()
        {
            System.out.print("Please make a selection."
                               +"\n1: Begin"
                               +"\n2: Exit"
                               +"\n");
        }

    private static void menueCatch()
        {   
            Scanner userIn= new Scanner(System.in);
            int userChoice=userIn.nextInt();

            String input="";

            switch(userChoice)
            {

                case 1:
                {
                 process();
                 break;
                }

                case 2:
                {

                 break;
                }
            }
        }

    private static void process()
    {
      Scanner userIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] numbers = new int[10];
        int count = 0;


        do 
            {

                System.out.print("Enter ten numbers with a space seperating each number: ");
                while (!userIn.hasNextInt()) 
                {
                    System.out.println("That's not a number!");
                    System.out.println("Re-enter a number: ");
                    userIn.next();
                }
                number = userIn.nextInt();
            } while (number < );

        for (int index = 0; index < numbers.length; index++) 
        {
            int num = userIn.nextInt();

            if (isNew(numbers, num)) 
            {
                numbers[count++] = num;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The number of distinct number is " + count);
        System.out.print("The distinct numbers are: ");
        for (int index = 0; index < count; index++) {
            System.out.print(numbers[index] + " ");
        }
    }

    private static boolean isNew(int[] numbers, int num) {

        for (int index : numbers){
            if (num == index) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

     private static char contOption()
        {
            char answer;
        Scanner userIn=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("\nDo you wish to enter another 10 numbers?(Y/N): ");
        answer=userIn.next().toUpperCase().charAt(0);

        return answer;
        }    






}
```

Comment: Use try catch while taking input,

Comment: If it crashes you should get a stack trace telling you where and why!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use `Scanner.hasNextInt`, or catch the exception.

Also:

> "Any advice would be appreciated."

I advise you to format your code according to the [Java Style Guide](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf) ... if you want other people to read it. (And formatting it before you ask them to read it would be a good idea ...)

- Use consistent indentation (4 spaces per indentation level)
- No line-breaks before `{` blocks ... except after a `;`.
- Use consistent whitespace between tokens according to the style guide.

I advise you to use `boolean` rather than `char` (e.g. `cont`) for control logic.